# useEffect() Hook doesn't update when State Change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Board from './Board';
import Player from '../functions/Player'

function Game() {

  const [computer, setComputer] = useState(Player(1,false));
  const [computerBoard, setComputerBoard] = useState(new Array(100).fill(-1));

  const sendAttack = (location) => {
    // Activates everytime I click Board component
    let compCopy = computer;
    compCopy.receiveAttack(location);
    setComputer(compCopy);
    setComputerBoard(compCopy.getHitBoard());
    console.log(compCopy.getHitBoard()); // always prints, each time I do sendAttack()
    // and the hitBoard does change, shows a different hitBoard everytime I click!
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('something has changed') // print (twice for some reason) only on render, why?
    
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('computer hit has changed') // prints only on render and on the first setAttack()
  },[computer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('computer board has changed') // prints on render
    // and once it works but only on first sendAttack()
  },[computerBoard])

  return (
    <div className="game">
      <Board hitBoard ={computer.getHitBoard()} sendAttack={sendAttack} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Game;
```

The problem is that I want that the `Board` components hitBoard `prop` will keep getting updated whenever `sendAttack()` has finished updating. But it never does update it except on render (and actually just one time for the first sendAttack()). I don't understand why when I `setComputer` it doesn't initiate a `useEffect()`

Is there an obvious mistake in my code? Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer given by @Atmas above, is correct. I'd tweak it a bit by having `receiveAttack()` return a new object that is a copy of the one passed in with the additional changes. That's a more robust solution to data management in general - don't modify objects, make new ones and return them. Also, that idea of comparing object IDs rather than the content of the object is something you're going to hit all the time in React and various React libraries.

Here's a useful guide that talks about exactly what you're trying to do - use an object as a React state variable:

https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-usestate-in-react-ecb9952e406c/#usinganobjectasastatevariablewithusestatehook

Also, you don't need a `useEffect()` to debug this stuff. Just a regular ol' console log placed right above your return statement will print when the component re-renders.

Comment: Hah. That's funny. I was debating with myself whether to include the immutable chain concept for that method too but thought I'd leave it be. Good additions!

Comment: I fixed my problem with @Atmas and then I implemented what you wrote as well. Thanks for the useful tips, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your compCopy is actually a new object. If the object isn't different then setComputer likely won't be different therefore the effect won't trigger. Try something like `let compCopy = makeANewCopyOf(computer)` such that compCopy is a brand new object that you have cloned yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much it worked! I replaced to `let compCopy = Player(1,false); ` and then I set compCopy to have all the same qualities as computers current. You were right, I wasn't copying it at all haha. Now I have and it works as it should.

Comment: Brilliant! It's good to learn how the system works so you can build trust on it. Glad you're working!